# 2400 mbps capable 5Ghz Wifi, gets ~400 (half) per device (capable of 1.2gbps) over 2.5gbe; How does it work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

**Note: No internet involved, just local.**

2 Wifi 6 devices (Macbooks), each capable of 1.2gbps.
Wifi 6 router (GL-MT3000) on 5ghz band capable of 2400mpbs connected to desktop over 2.5gbe link.
Desktop is hosting open-speedtest, 1 way data transfer at a time.

1 device at a time saturates around 1gbps, I expect some loss.
2 devices at the same time reach around 400mpbs per device, half per device. Combined still 1gbps.

**Since the Wifi router is capable of 2400mbps I would assume they should still be able to saturate 1gbps per device more or less, total around 2gbps.**
That's not the case tho, what's the missing part, will getting a 5400mbps 5ghz capable wifi help?

Comment: Does the 400mpbs figure apply for each device, or is it the total bandwidth on the router?

Comment: per device, both still pulling or pushing 1gbps total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both devices take turns, it halves the speed. That much was known already.
The missing part was that for some reason I thought 2400mbps availability makes any difference, it does not.
Since each turn can only benefit at max 1.2gbps of the available 2400mbps.

It will only benefit if:
the devices were capable of more than 1.2 gbps, then each turn would transfer more data.
Or this was a tri-band wifi router, additional 5ghz band provides both device their own lane, no need for turns.
Or some additional capability?

Answer (score -1):

Multiple WiFi devices do slow down the network.

Basically, your WiFi router cannot communicate with all the
connected devices simultaneously, because it is using the same
frequency for all the devices. As a result, each device will take
turns in sending its data packets across this same frequency.

The speed loss you experience depends on the number of
connected devices, and does not relate to your internet speed.
Another factor is that a slower device will cause the faster
devices to slow down, because it will monopolize the router
for longer time.

WiFi routers use various methods to avoid collisions between devices.
You may read about it in the article
[Difference between CSMA/CA and CSMA/CD](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-csma-ca-and-csma-cd).

To avoid this slowing down effect, you may use various methods
that depend on the router:

- Use a router that has multiple antennas, meaning a
  Multi-Band WiFi Router. For example, connect one device to 2.4GHz
  and the other to the 5GHz band.
- Use a router and devices that use a faster and more evolved protocol,
  such as AC WiFi & WiFI 6.

More information can be found, for example the Netgear article
[Did you know that adding more devices to your network (and yes, that thermostat counts!) slows your WiFi network?](https://www.netgear.com/hub/wifi/routers/step-up-to-ac-wireless-technology/)

Comment: Did you use a boilerplate answer without reading the question? Your bullet points don't make sense. He already has a dual-band Wi-Fi 6 router and both clients in question are Wi-Fi 6. Also, Wi-Fi 6 APs can theoretically speak to multiple Wi-Fi 6 clients truly simultaneously via either MU-MIMO or OFDMA if the devices in question all support it.

Comment: @Spiff: The poster's answer says the same - the devices take turn and halve the speed, would you downvote it too? Excuse me for thinking that giving more general advice to future readers was a good idea.